# Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to get place details by giving place id in the url as shown below.

```
func findingPlaceDetailsFromPlaceId(id : String){


   var urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=\(id)&key=\(apiServerKey)"
    urlString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    //println(urlString)
    if placesTask.taskIdentifier > 0 && placesTask.state == .Running {
        placesTask.cancel()

    }
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    placesTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: urlString)!) {data, response, error in

        println(error)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:nil, error:nil) as? NSDictionary {

            if let results = json["result"] as? NSArray {
                println(results.count)
                for rawPlace:AnyObject in results {
                    let dict = rawPlace as! NSDictionary
                if let location = dict["geometry"]?["location"] as? NSDictionary{

                    let lat = location["lat"] as! CLLocationDegrees
                    let long = location["lng"] as! CLLocationDegrees
                    self.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long)
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {


        }

    }

    self.placesTask.resume()
}
```

The given url is a valid one. If I put the same url in google I'm getting valid results, but when I run it in my app it's showing "Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled".

Comment: it seems that you have canceled the session. kindly comment the two lines if placesTask.taskIdentifier > 0 && placesTask.state == .Running {
        placesTask.cancel()

    }

Comment: That should really be the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for my above error.
I was calling findingPlaceDetailsFromPlaceId(id : String) method from the didSelectRow of the searchResultControllerView. As soon after calling the method I was dismissing the searchResultControllerView. It was leading to above error. Now am dismissing the searchResultControllerView in dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) like shown below.

```
 func findingPlaceDetailsFromPlaceId(id : String){

   var urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=\(id)&key=\(apiServerKey)"
    urlString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    if placesTask.taskIdentifier > 0 && placesTask.state == .Running {
        placesTask.cancel()

    }
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    placesTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: urlString)!) {data, response, error in

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        if let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:nil, error:nil) as? NSDictionary {

            if let results = json["result"] as? NSDictionary {

                if let location = results["geometry"]?["location"] as? NSDictionary{
                    let lat = location["lat"] as! CLLocationDegrees
                    let long = location["lng"] as! CLLocationDegrees
                    self.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat,long)

                }
            }
        }
//This is what I added
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            //Dismissing the ResultControllerView
            self.searchController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
                //Pushing the view back to main view after completion
                performSegueWithIdentifier("unwindFromSelectLocation", sender: self)
            })



        }

    }
```

Problem solved.. Hope it will be usefull for others!!!